# Piping tcpdump traffic via SSH - but no root ssh access

Tags: ssh, centos, sudo, tcpdump

**The situation**

I would like to use Wireshark to analyze traffic on one of our servers, but I don't want to install Wireshark on the server itself. I understand that I can [pipe tcpdump traffic](https://serverfault.com/questions/362529/how-can-i-sniff-the-traffic-of-remote-machine-with-wireshark) via SSH to my local machine (Ubuntu) which has Wireshark installed.

**The problem**

I cannot login to the server with a root account because that is disabled. I have sudo rights, but when logged in to the server the command `sudo tcpdump` does not work. The command below (with or without sudo) won't work:

```
$ ssh john@server-abc.com "sudo tcpdump -s 0 -U -n -w - -i eth0 not port 22" > /tmp/remote
```

**The question**

Is there a way to get this working? If so - how?

Comment: Do you need to pipe data ? Can you run the tcpdump for as long as you need, and then use wireshark later to review the data ?

Comment: That is an option I didn't consider yet!

Comment: By "does not work", does that mean you get an error message?

Comment: I guess tcpdump is not in the allowed commands for sudo, and this seems to be the case for some servers, not all. So on some I can use sudo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can run this command via sudo on the server to capture the data first, and 
then send the resulting file back to your workstation to review the data

```
sudo tcpdump -i eth0 -s 65535 -w /tmp/wireshark
```

Answer (score 4):

Without `sudo` the command doesn't have privileges to capture the device:

> tcpdump: eth0: You don't have permission to capture on that device

But with `sudo` it would, but being run after `ssh`, it never gets password input for `sudo` on the remote server, so the solution is use `-S` (`man sudo`) and pipe password for `sudo` as follows:

```
ssh john@server-abc.com "echo sudo_password | sudo -S tcpdump -s 0 -U -n -w - -i eth0 not port 22" > /tmp/remote"
```

On the one hand this is good for the automation with no getting `sudo` password promts and, to have completely automated code/script you would add `sshpass -p password ssh...`.

However on the server where others can easily read your sudo password provided as open text during the `ssh` session that's not recommended from the security perspectives. So, to have a `sudo` with `ssh` and be safe use `ssh -t`

With `-t` it's impossible to pipe `ssh "sudo command"| command` for example`ssh -t server "cd path/to/directory && sudo"|grep "text"` but it IS possible with ussage of -S and echoing password, e.g. `ssh server 'echo password | sudo -S ls -l'| grep 'a'`

Comment: Perhaps you could expand this a bit and explain your answer a bit?

Comment: @sim I added an explanation.